# WiFi connects, no internet

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, mojave

Yesterday my wifi suddenly stopped working on my Mid 2014 MBP, Mojave 10.14.1

Network is up, as other devices can connect, same issue with mobile hotspot.

Network diag says there is no issue. The toolbar icon successfully shows a connection to either of my wifi networks.

But the browser/curl cannot connect. Chrome just says "no internet"

I am unable to even connect directly to the router admin panel (by IP)

I tried restarting and resetting PRAM.

Tried [deleting plist files associated with the wifi](https://www-iphonehacks-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.iphonehacks.com/2014/11/wi-fi-problems-mac-os-x-yosemite.html/amp?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHCAFYAYABAQ%3D%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iphonehacks.com%2F2014%2F11%2Fwi-fi-problems-mac-os-x-yosemite.html) as well, no luck

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing troubleshioting with the link above, in the Network > Advanced > Hardware tab

click on the Hardware tab and change Configuration from Automatically to Manual.

Then click on MTU, and select Manual. Enter 1453 as the MTU Number.

This fixed things, does anyone know what might have caused this?

Comment: Does it only work with 1453? What if you set it back to 1500/1501?